# How to echo data-ac-chart="'bar'" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I can't 'echo' the ' ' closers in jQuery.
I tried this method:

```
$('#run').append("<pre><code class='prettyprint'>"+data+"</code></pre> <div data-ac-chart="+"'"+"bar"+"'"+" data-ac-data='data' data-ac-config='config' class='chart'></div>");
```

But this will show:

```
<div data-ac-chart="bar" data-ac-data="data" data-ac-config="config" class="chart"></div>
```

How to edit the jQUery code to the result will be this:

```
<div data-ac-chart="'bar'" data-ac-data="data" data-ac-config="config" class="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I have answered below, but actually I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. In your expected result, the `<pre> ...</pre>` fragment doesn't appear -- so what's the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the neatest solution, but you could escape the double quotes.

```
<div data-ac-chart=\"'" + data + "'\"></div>
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecngrudw/)

```
$('#run').append("<pre><code class='prettyprint'>"+data+"</code></pre> <div data-ac-chart=\"'" + data + "'\" data-ac-data='data' data-ac-config='config' class='chart'></div>");
```

For a neater solution, I'd suggest checking out a JS templating engine.

---

Alternatively, you could also just change/add the value *after* you have appended the element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7evz5x1e/)

```
$('#run [data-ac-chart]').attr('data-ac-chart', "'" + data + "'");
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I will accept this answer, but need to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to add `\` before the apostrophe, like this:

```
data-ac-chart="+"\'"+"bar"+"\'"
```

Josh was right with :

```
data-ac-chart="+\"'"+"bar"+"'\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape such characters using a backslash.

A) With **single quotes** around HTML attributes: (not recommended, here you have to escape the created attribute value)

```
var output = "<div data-ac-chart='\\\'bar\\\'' data-ac-data='data' data-ac-config='config' class='chart'></div>";
```

The multitude of backslashes is required here to mask the backslash and single quote inside the attribute from JavaScript. JS then outputs HTML with escaped attribute values:

```
"<div data-ac-chart='\'bar\'' data-ac-data='data' data-ac-config='config' class='chart'></div>"
```

B) With **double quotes** around HTML attributes: (recommended, write beautiful markup and everything will work out :-)

```
var output = '<div data-ac-chart="\'bar\'" data-ac-data="data" data-ac-config="config" class="chart"></div>';
```

C) A more readable approach using **placeholders and string replacement**:

```
var output = '<div data-ac-chart="{chart}" data-ac-data="{data}" data-ac-config="{config}" class="chart"></div>'
  .replace( '{chart}', '\'bar\'' )
  .replace( '{data}', 'data' )
  .replace( '{config}', 'config' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating strings is cumbersome and as you experience quite difficult to debug. That's why I recommend using a template approach as supported by [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

```
<!-- in your HTML -->
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<div>
  <pre>
    <code class='prettyprint'>
       <%=data%>
    </code>
  </pre> 
  <div data-ac-chart='bar' data-ac-data='data' data-ac-config='config' class='chart'>
  </div>
</div>
</script>

/* in your javascript */
$('#run').append(_.template($("#template").html())({ 
    data : "var function(x) = { some code };"
}));
```

Make sure to [load the underscorejs library](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/underscore.js/). A working example is available in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shwn06jo/)